# MongoDB comparing dates only without times

Tags: mongodb

How do I query for a date field in MongoDB with the date only, and not times?  For example, if MongoDB stores July 7, 2015 with *any* time, I want to match that day only with today's date.

In MySQL, I would do `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE DATE(date_field) = DATE(NOW());`

Notice how MySQL has a function to change the *date_field* to the date only during matching.  Can I do this in MongoDB with a similar function during matching? Like `Collection.find({ dateonly(datetimefield): dateonly(new Date() });` or something of the like?

I understand Mongo stores date/times in GMT, so I would also have to convert the stored GMT date+time from GMT to Local before matching the date only, but to get me started, would like to know if I can strip the time off of a date match.  For example, if GMT now is July 8 at 03:00 but Local Eastern Time US is July 7 at 23:00 then I would want to match July 7.

Comment: Whats the format of date in your mongoDB?

Comment: The date field format is the same as the Javascript date object.  Like: `new Date()`.

Comment: Thinking about this now...perhaps the best solution is to store another field that is in numerical format that represents the local date?  Like 20150706 for YYYYMMDD? Then just do numerical comparisons?

Comment: Facing the same problem, I also decided similar approach and store my date field itself as String. This removes the power of date comparison for analysis but works for my case. Mongo should have a simpler way of date comparison!

Comment: Cool. Yeah, seems like the easiest way. This is useful for events like birthdays where only the date matters.  For example, if the user's local time has a MMDD date of 0706 (July 6), and the birthday field has 20150706, a string comparison against the last 4 digits shows 0706 matches the user's current date, so I can wish them a Happy Birthday.  If I had to do GMT to Local conversions, it gets complicated. Especially complicated if the user moves across time zones where their birthday could start/end earlier or later if GMT datetime was used as the comparing field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated 2018-06-26 fixed up the code to use moment() instead of new Date()**

I solved this by use MomentJS Timezone (http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to convert a local date/time to a date-only numerical field, then I store the date as a number.

In my javascript code (outside of MongoDB):

```
var localDateOnly = function(timezone, d) {
  if (d == undefined) { d = new Date(); } // current date/time
  return Number( moment(d).tz(timezone).format("YYYYMMDD") );
}
```

Then I store a date-only field in the Mongo record.

```
var myDate = localDateOnly("America/New_York");  // today, in YYYYMMDD number
db.birthdays.insert(
  { dateonly: myDate, event: "This day is my birthday!" }
);
```

Then in my Javascript code, I can easily query today, tomorrow, specific days, etc.

```
// today
var myDate = localDateOnly("America/New_York");
db.birthdays.find( { dateonly: myDate } );

// tomorrow
var myDate = localDateOnly(
  "America/New_York",
  moment().add( 1, "days" )
);  // tomorrow
db.birthdays.find( { dateonly: myDate } );

// someone wants to know birthdays on the calendar on July 15, 2015,
// no timezone math needed, just type the date in YYYYMMDD format
db.birthdays.find( { dateonly: 20150715 } );
```

Hope this helps someone.  Decided to store as a number for performance and validity checking.  Before insert, I check for a valid date using the moment package as well:

```
moment( 20150715, "YYYYMMDD", true ).isValid()  // returns true & allowed to store in the database
moment( 150715, "YYYYMMDD", true ).isValid()  // returns false, don't insert into db
```

Code was cleaner when storing integers that represented dates, and made it easy for mongo to find ranges.  Like, find birthdays in 2015 would be `{"$gte": 20150101, "$lte": 20151231}` or `{"$gte": 20150000, "$lte": 20159999}`.

Answer (score 41):

I guess You should make a range query between the start of the day and its ending(or without ending if you are talking about today). Something like this

```
db.collection.find({
  "date" : {"$gte": new Date("2015-07-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "$lt": new Date("2015-07-08T00:00:00.000Z")}
})
```

Answer (score 18):

You can extract the date as string at any given format and compare it with your date at that format using aggregation pipiline

```
$addFields: { "creationDate":  {$dateToString:{format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt"}}}},
{$match :  { creationDate:  {$eq: req.query.date}}
```

Comment: [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator works only for aggregation but OP wants for `find` operator.

Comment: @alexandre-rousseau i am using the ```$dateToString``` without problems with ```find```

Answer (score 14):

It's possible with $expr

```
{ $expr: {$eq: ["2021-03-29", { $dateToString: {date: "$dateField", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is my proposed solution:

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
  {"date": {$gte: new Date("2015-07-07T00:00:00.000Z")}},
  {"date": {$lt: new Date("2015-07-08T00:00:00.000Z")}}
  ]
})
```

Comment: Conventional Date/Time fields get complicated when referring to special calendar days like an anniversary or birthday.  To make the code simple, I now store a "number" field in the format of YYYYMMDD.  Easy to convert that number to string, then see if the last 4 digits (the MMDD part) match the current user's month and day.  If so, I wish them a Happy Birthday.  If this was done with a conventional date field, I'd have to do time zone conversions to determine if they are located in a time zone where their birthday is the current day.

Answer (score 1):

I did a combination of the answers of Crash_Override and Maxim_PontyUshenko. Use Moment.js and the $gt, $lt mongo operators.

```
ship_date: {
  $lt: moment().hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).add(28, "days").toDate(),
  $gte: moment().hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).toDate()
}
```