# Using the $eq Operator on a Date in Mongo Filter Logic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a variety of filters in one of my Node/Mongo endpoints that filter on dates. For instance here is one that's working perfectly:

```
  // first purchase date after filter
  if (firstPurchaseDateAfter && firstPurchaseDateBefore === "") {
    let firstPurchaseDateAfterDate = new Date(firstPurchaseDateAfter);
    search["firstTransaction.timestamp"] = {
      $gt: firstPurchaseDateAfterDate
    };
  }
```

Basically, I take in a string value, convert it to a date and then do a comparison, in this case using the `$gt` operator.

The value being targeted looks like this:

```
"timestamp": "2016-07-26T08:00:54.232Z"
```

So, as I say, the above logic works perfectly.

What I'm wondering is why a similarly built filter that targets a specific date using the `$eq` operator does not work. This is the code:

```
  // first purchase date equals filter
  if (firstPurchaseDateEquals) {
    let firstPurchaseDateEqualsDate = new Date(firstPurchaseDateEquals);
    search["firstTransaction.timestamp"] = {
      $eq: firstPurchaseDateEqualsDate
    };
  }
```

Can one not use the `$eq` operator in this manner on a date value? What's the issue here?

Comment: You seem to be comparing a Date and a string?

Comment: it's a string, not ISODate. Do `$eq: firstPurchaseDateEqualsDate.toISOString()`.

Comment: Will try that. Why does it work in the first case but not the second case? I guess because the equality check is much more specific.

Comment: it doesn't work in first case either.

Comment: Actually, it does -- in the sense that my data is filtered correctly. Maybe you mean it will not be an exact check? If I pass in firstPurchaseDateAfter=2015 and firstPurchaseDateBefore=2016, I get results with all dates in between Jan 1 of 2015 and Jan 1 of 2016.

Comment: I mean that when I insert a document `{"timestamp": "2016-07-26T08:00:54.232Z"}` the search `{timestamp:{$gt: new Date("2010-07-26T08:00:54.232Z")}}` returns nothing https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Tgu5MISpOj

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The value passed in from the front-end user is a string, which I then convert to a date. When I run a comparison on that, using $gt, and $lt, it works. Like this `{$gt: new Date("2016")}}`

Comment: To clarify, for a passed in string value of "2016", `console.log(firstPurchaseDateEqualsDate.toISOString())` and `console.log(firstPurchaseDateEqualsDate)` return the exact same value: `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: Dates are tricky. Have a look here. Basically your best bet for $eq is to do less than and greater than withing a very small range (either hour, or 24 hours if you want to completely ignore the time part of the date, up to you)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272471/mongodb-comparing-dates-only-without-times