# MongoDB $dateFromString error in aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am facing this error while using `$dateFromString`

> MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: date with value 2022-09-08T12:45:30.811Z

In my schema, I did `{ timestamps: true }` to save `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      createdAt: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: '$createdAt'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

The object in mongodb is saved as:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6319e3ea8fec56ded0173275"),
  isAvailable: true,
  createdAt: 2022-09-08T12:45:30.811Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-09-08T12:45:30.811Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: Please do not post your sample documents as image. We cannot check the datatype for the field because it could be the display/rendering from your db client. Instead, please post the raw json document.

Comment: the error clearly says what is wrong, `$dateFromString` expects a string, not $date

Comment: @ds97 so the field is `date` or `string`?

Comment: @ray field is date when {timestamp: true} , this is why it is giving error, I dont know how to feed in string when it was saved as date.

Comment: @ds97 but then why do you need to use `$dateFromString`? The function is used for converting string into date, but here you already have the date then the conversion is unnecessary

Comment: because, I am trying to group by date, I need to group 2022-09-08 only, however, it is grouping 2022-09-08T12:45:30, 2022-09-08T12:45:32, 2022-09-08T12:45:33, for the same date,  I am getting 3 groups because are 3 different timestamp of the same day whereas there should be only one group. This is the primary issue. Is there any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB comparing dates only without times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272471/mongodb-comparing-dates-only-without-times)